# How do I draw a line graph in Android?

Tags: android, graph

I want to draw a line graph that updates in real time, similar to the graph we see in the Windows Task Manager when we want to take a look at CPU and memory usage over time.

Is there already a library designed for Android that will allow me to do this easily? Or will I have to write my own? (And if I do have to do this, how would I bring up some sort of canvas on an Android activity?)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a library designed for this and my guess is you would have to draw it yourself.

[This example in the API Demos](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/os/Sensors.html) project uses the built in sensors to draw a running graph on the canvas, looks like what your are trying to recreate, but replace the sensor input with a data feed or something.

Comment: Apparently, there are actually some libraries, according to one of the comments I've gotten.

Comment: I saw that, good to know. I can't tell, but do any of them allow a real time/animated style like the CPU monitor?

Comment: Apparently, AndroidPlot does.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at AChartEngine. We use it in many Android projects and it's brilliant. It's free, it's still under development (new features) and the author is very helpfull.

http://www.achartengine.org/

Comment: From your experience, will this allow me to do real-time updating, like that in the CPU usage graph in Windows Task Manager?

Comment: I use AChartEngines gauge in one of our apps. You can drive your car and the needle is updated permanently. It's working great. I didn't try that with line or barcharts. The later need to be drawn entirely - at least I think so - on every update. Anayway, I would give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx? The library is rather large but it may work for you

Comment: $299+ for a chart-drawing library? I think I'll pass, especially after finding out that there are open source solutions.

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow: but the real question is "how good are the open source solutions?". $299 is worth saving several hours of my time hacking around a terrible library. I'm not assuming that either one is good or bad, but dismissing based on a few hundred bucks seems premature.

Comment: It's $399 if you include the subscription. I've used it and it works great for a graph-heavy app, but if you're just drawing a single line graph, it's a bit much.